# Different color svg image depending on the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, browser, svg, colors

Well, here is my problem. 
I'm developing the front end of a website using rails. and I'm using svg images. If you go to http://de-regalos-qa.herokuapp.com/products/9 you would see an image with cards (visa, mastercard, etc) this image looks like transparent or with a very light opacity but if you download the image you would see the image with the original colors. This only happens with chrome and firefox but not with safari. This happens only with two of the images from all my site. I dont understand why.

[Chrome screenshot:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UrHNZ.png)

Comment: your links don't work - attach a screeshots instead of it

Comment: Try this: http://de-regalos-qa.herokuapp.com

Comment: Without www ! http://de-regalos-qa.herokuapp.com/products and then select one product with "show" button

Comment: your svg is just a wrapper around a base64 encoded png >< wat r u doin?